# How do people modify android apps that doesnt have source code

Tags: android, android-studio

I know there's decompilers but decompilers doesnt work perfectly there will mostly some errors etc.

So like Whatsapp Plus, youtube vanced etc. How people modify apps? do they use decompiler,fix errors and then edit apps source code or do they use something else?

Answer (score 0):

Some apps may have their source code available on GitHub, in which case you can fork the repository and apply your edits.  Needless to say, you should always respect the license.

You can also submit bug reports to the maintainer, which would also be considered "good form".

If what you are truly trying to do is reverse engineer the app, you may find more info on hacker boards.  I don't know many software developers who take kindly to having their hard work stolen.

Note that if you consider yourself capable of "fixing bugs" in apps that you haven't developed yourself, perhaps you would consider developing your own app.

Comment: The reason I want to see/change code it is I want to see the code to improve myself and edit some apps and add features to it (to use myself) like adding features to whatsapp  etc.(I do not plan to steal someones code or copy his app)

Comment: Looking at decompiled or reverse-engineered code is not of much use, unless your goal is to learn how the decompiler or reverse-engineering tool reads code.  These tools don't think like humans and thus the resulting code will likely will have been obfuscated and thus, not quite clear to a human reader.

Answer (score 0):

In order for an app to be legally modified by a third party, the app must be open source (have the source code available to anyone), ex. Linux. However, the front-end source code of web apps, like youtube, can be viewed by anyone through browser developer tools. A decompiler can, sometimes, produce source code that produces the same result as the original, but is, most of the time, obscurified.